# Type definition for type Request are incomplete in ask-sdk V2

Tags: typescript, alexa-skills-kit

I am using typescript definitions provided in ask-sdk V2. Everything works fine but when I over over intent of request.intent, it is giving me an error "Property 'intent' does not exist on type 'Request'".
I am guessing type definitions are inocomplete here.

```
canHandle(handlerInput: Alexa.HandlerInput) {
 const { request } = handlerInput.requestEnvelope;

 return (
   request.type === intents.type.IntentRequest &&
   request.intent.name === intents.LocateBranch
 );
},
```

Comment: Please report it here so it gets fixed: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues